# What casuses this message after editing index.html with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I edit various lines in index.html to add the version to some attributes and I get the following message at runtime...

SyntaxError: illegal character[Learn More]

The PowerShell code to edit the file is as follows...

```
$source = "C:\F\src"

$pathToIndex = "$source\MyAppNet\MyAppNet2.0\MyAppWeb\MyCo.WebApp\index.html"
#$fileForEdit = Get-Item $pathToIndex
$addition = "?v=11.0.0.2572"

# Allow edit...
sp $pathToIndex IsReadOnly $false

(Get-Content $pathToIndex) | 
ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -notmatch '\?v='-and $_ -notmatch 'MyCo.WebApi/signalr/hubs' -and $_ -notmatch 'family=Material'){  # exclusions.
        if($_ -match '\s<script src="(.*)"'){
            $pattern = [regex]::Escape($matches[1])
            $line = $_ -replace $pattern, ($matches[1] + $addition)
            Write-Host $line -fore green
            $line
        }elseif($_ -match 'href="(.*)" rel="'){
            $pattern = [regex]::Escape($matches[1])
            $line = $_ -replace $pattern, ($matches[1] + $addition)
            Write-Host $line -fore Gray
            $line
        }elseif($_ -match '" href="(.*)"'){ #for href as second attribute
            $pattern = [regex]::Escape($matches[1])
            $line = $_ -replace $pattern, ($matches[1] + $addition)
            Write-Host $line -fore red
            $line
        }else{
            $_
            Write-Host $_ -fore Yellow
        }            

    }
    else{
        $_
    }

} |
Out-File $pathToIndex

sp $pathToIndex IsReadOnly $true
```

Is the Out-File tanking things by adding a special character(s) of some sort?  If prior to the edit from our build script, the file is manually edited all is OK. If we compare the good/bad files with something like WinMerge, they look the same.

Puzzled doesn't come close to summing things up right now.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: ..Why are you manually editing `index.html` with powershell..?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell problem. Use the developer tools in the browser that throws the `SyntaxError` warning (sounds firefox-y to me) to find the offending character or statement, see if your `$addition` value was replaced nearby

Comment: We did that and it really didn't show anything (it is Firefox).  We compared the files and they were exact or appeared so.  I switched the PowerShell script to Set-Content instead, while also replacing all the other code with a simple text replace of a tag in the .html file with the actual build version.